# Use Google authentication token with Firebase

Tags: .net, firebase, google-authentication

I have a .NET application (not a web app) where users are already authenticated by Google Authorization, and therefore a token has been issued.

I'd like this application to store user data to Firebase with a user read-write security rule of type: "$user_id === auth.uid".

Since you may authenticate to Firebase with Google, is there a way that the application would pass to Firebase an already Google issued token?

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase REST API only takes Firebase JWT tokens. You can take the information from the Google token and mint a JWT from it, using one of the [libraries Firebase provides](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries) for the purpose.

This is covered in the [User Authentication section of the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html).

Comment: I wanted to avoid the need for a server to generate JWT tokens, I was hoping for a .NET library that could authenticate via Google like the Firebase Javascript library does.

Comment: Although Firebase doesn't provide such a library, there are probably .NET OAuth clients out there. After you use one of those to authenticate the user, you can still mint a JWT based on the information.